# Problems with NaN when use jsonData and count variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, concatenation

The Problem:

[image: The Problem]

When I try to concat in `.html(jsondatareg.recibido+i)` my explorer returns `NaN` value because the Js can't concat the two "strings" values.

My code:

```
var params = '&cedula='+cedula;
$.post('classes/recibirDatos', params, function(jsondatareg){
    for(var i = 0; i < jsondatareg.contador; i++){
        $('#recibido'+i).html(jsondatareg.recibido+i);
        console.log(jsondatareg.recibido+i);
    }
},'json');
```

The values:

[image: The values]

Comment: jsondatareg["recibido"+i]

Comment: recibido0 is wrong. It is not an integer. What result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the `json` property like an `array` , try this :

```
var params = '&cedula='+cedula;

$.post('classes/recibirDatos', params, function(jsondatareg){

    for(var i = 0; i < jsondatareg.contador; i++){
        $('#recibido'+i).html(jsondatareg["recibido" + i]);

        console.log(jsondatareg["recibido" + i]);
    }

},'json');
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I use this method and works fine. You're the best! <3